# Issue with accessing hosted content via apple app store in-app purchases: 'The folder “Contents” doesn’t exist.'

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, storekit, iap-hosted-content

I have been working with hosted in-app purchasable content and am running into an issue. I've been able to get the content to download and such but sometimes run into an error.
Here is the code I use to access the download:

```
if let hostedContentPath = contentURL?.appendingPathComponent("Contents", isDirectory: true) {
    do {
        try FileManager().moveFileToLibrary(hostedPath: hostedContentPath)
            onSuccess(contentIdentifier)
        } catch let err as NSError {
            onError(contentIdentifier, err)
        }
    }
}
```

This code is part of an extension of the SKDownload object provided by StoreKit.
I have an extension for the FileManager:

```
func moveFileToLibrary(hostedPath: URL) throws {
        
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
        
    let files = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: hostedPath.relativePath)
        
    for file in files {
            
        let sourcePath: URL = hostedPath.appendingPathComponent(file)
        var destinationPath: URL = fileManager.getLibraryPath(folders: [file])
            
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destinationPath.path) {
            print("[FileManager] File already present")
            return
        }
        // Move file to Library
        try fileManager.moveItem(at: sourcePath, to: destinationPath)
        // Set removal from backup
        var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
        resourceValues.isExcludedFromBackup = true
        try destinationPath.setResourceValues(resourceValues)
            
        print("[FileManager] File moved")
    }
}
```

`getLibraryPath` simply returns the path of the in-app download in the library directory of the app.
But sometimes I get the error: 'The folder “Contents” doesn’t exist'. However, the download has completed. Has anyone dealt with this issue before? Am I handling something wrong?

Thanks a bunch,

Brendin

Edit: Every so often I get this error when an SKDownload has the failed downloadState: '“mzafbenc.16634573027684271354” couldn’t be moved to “StoreKit” because an item with the same name already exists'. Does anyone know if this is related or if it is something I can fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, after downloading content I got SKDownload with status "failed" and also have error description like your - "mzafbenc.16634573027684271354” couldn’t be moved to “StoreKit” ..."

Simple solution for this is cleaning dir in your app using `FileManager` every time in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, for next path: *Library/Caches/StoreKit*

As for "Contents does not exists", make sure, that you finished transaction **after** all manipulation with downloaded content.